# Got +3 score for an upvoted answer

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I doubt whether it's a problem or it works like this only, but I got just a `+3` score for an upvoted answer. And this isn't the first time it happens to me. Once I got a `+5` score for an upvoted answer.

What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Might be one upvote and one downvote be there on the same question, resulting in +5 and -2 (+3 accumulative score).

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj. No they are shown indivudually.. Anyways, I got my problem resolved..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably hit the daily [rep cap of 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). You might have been at 197 just before that, allowing you only 3 more points for that particular upvote.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Thanks.. that was the problemm :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the answer you have given to [Compile Error on Java 7 Diamond Operator: ArrayList<>();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630006/compile-error-on-java-7-diamond-operator-arraylist) then the reason it the reputation cap.

[image: screenshot]

Once you get 200 points from up-votes, the successive up-votes don't give you any reputation. The reputation you gain from accepted answers (whenever you accept answers given for your questions, or you got your answer accepted by other users), and bounties are not included in the limit. That is why you got 217 points on that day.

Comment: Rich people problems. :)

Comment: @jmort253.. It's not a problem with me.. It happened one more time, but i didn't bothered.. But it happened again, I though I should know what is the reason..